# Hubspot API - Get contact by email is giving HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: python-2.7, api, django-views, http-status-code-401, hubspot

I am requesting a Search for contact by email using Hubspot API

I kept on getting HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized.

The request is been sent from a view in Django. See code below.

Of course the email@domain.com and xxxxxx are repalced by the proper values and just for clarification I am sure I am using the API Key and NOT the access_token.

```
xurl = "https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/email/email@domain.com/profile?hapikey=xxxxxx"

req = urllib2.Request(xurl)

response = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()  Error occurs at this line, says Django

statistics = json.loads(response)

print(statistics["contacts"])
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

401 usually means "Permission denied" try to check if you use correct API_KEY.

also I would recommend to use a library like [hubspot3](https://pypi.org/project/hubspot3/) instead of dealing with http requests directly

Answer (score 0):

1.Check the HAPI key again, it should not be expired.
2.Just to make sure the URL formed is correct you can also simply paste the URL in Postman and check for the error.

It should work fine unless there are any issues with the URL-https://api.hubapi.com/contacts/v1/contact/email/emailid@test.com/profile?hapikey=****